# NodeJs and Express: is there any risk my source code can be seen?

Tags: windows-server-2008, node.js

i am new to nodejs and express deployment...

i want to upload my files to my windows server machine, but i am afraid my source code can be retrieved using some url like http://myip:8080/app.js

Where should i put my files when i deploy my nodeJS app?
Additional question: does anyone know where should i put my username and password for database instead of inside the source code?

Answer (score 1):

It is up to you to make sure that there are no routes in your Express server that can serve your source files.  This is usually easy to achieve by just making sure that the files you do want served are in a different location from your source files and that the means you use for serving the other files cannot ever be used to get to your source files.

An individual route such as:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile("/assets/index.html");
});
```

will only ever serve that one file.

Where you have to be careful is when you use some sort of automatic routing such as with `express.static()`.  In that case, you have to make sure that you only expose just a sub-directory that contains your public assets (HTML files, CSS files, client-side JS files, etc...) and does not accidentally allowing serving of any of your server-side source files.

This can usually be done very easily by simply separating out the public assets into a different part of the file hierarchy:

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

This will only serve files that are in a `public` sub-directory from your app directory.  So, you could have a structure like this:

```
/user
    /me
       /myApp         (server-side source files are in here)
           /public    (public client-side files are in here)
```

Oh, and it goes without saying that your server needs to be generally secure so that it can't be compromised in other ways (not through your Express app) which would allow an attacker access to the file system.  Among other things, there is usually a firewall configured that only allows http requests on port 80 or 443 to get through from the outside world to your server.